# Dealing with 3 separate arrayLists and utilizing them in a first come first serve algorithm

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am reading in an input file that is structured as follows:

I was able to successfully readin the file and parse it. I create 3 seperate arraylists to store "Process, Arrival, and Burst".

Now i am having trouble implementing fcfs with these 3 arraylists. Should i be using Lists instead of arraylists instead? I need to print out the a timeline of what occurs at each time for 0 < timeUnitsRunning(essentially a gant chart) . Any help would be extremely appreciated, thanks!

[image: Output Example]

[image: processclass][image: eventsclass]

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement for first come first serve?

Comment: Do not create 3 lists. Java is an **Object Oriented** language, and you should use it. Create a class with 3 fields: `process`, `arrival`, `burst`. Then create a *single* list of objects of that class.

Comment: It is difficult to help you, when the desired outcome is not known. What does *"print out the a timeline"* mean? Show example. Click *edit* to update the question. Do not show example in a comment.

Comment: I am a bit confused as by what you mean by creating a single list of objects of that class if i am going to have an "x" amount of process. how would i go about parsing the input file for an "x" amount of processes and initializing them to those 3 fields for each process. ps. output example edited in orig post! thanks!

Comment: @Andreas were you able to check out the output i provided?

Comment: @dre You example output doesn't seem to use `timeunitsrunning` for anything.

Comment: @Andreas that output example has 30 has its timeunitsrunning. but thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a general outline of one way to do this:

- Create a class for representing a `Process`, with fields `int id`, `int arrival` and `int burst`
- Parse the input and build an `ArrayList<Process>`
- Sort the list by `arrival`, using `Collections.sort()`
- Add two extra fields to the class: `int selected` and `int finished`
- Iterate the list and assign values to the new fields, such that `selected` is the later of `arrival` of itself or `finished` of the previous process, and `finished = arrival + burst`
- Create another class called `Event`, with fields `int time` and `String description`
- Build the three events for each Process and add to an `ArrayList<Event>`
- Sort the list by `time`, again using `Collections.sort()`

You should now have all the data needed to generate the output you want.

Comment: hey andreas, everything works great except i am having trouble sorting out the event class by time. any suggestions?

Comment: Can't suggest anything without knowing what the trouble is.

Comment: just updated the post with my two classes(events and processes). The processes are printing fine, just not in order of time. And i dont exactly know how to use the comparable/comparator in this case

Comment: The `ArrayList<Event>` I was referring to in the 2nd-last bullet is a list *outside* of `Process`, with 3 events from each process, with a total of 9 `Event` objects in your example.